# Editing two associated objects in one Edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a couple of classes like this:

```
public class Widget
{
    public string WidgetId {get; set;)
    public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Rack { get; set; }
    public string Bin { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}
```

In the Widget's Edit View I allow the user to edit the Location fields as well liek this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(item => item.LocationId)
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location.Bin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location.Bin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location.Bin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location.Rack, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location.Rack, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location.Rack, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And here are my Actions

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var widget = db.Widgets.Find(id);

    return View(widget);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "WidgetId,Location,LocationId")] Widget widget)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Widgets.Attach(widget);
        db.Locations.Attach(widget.Location);

        db.Entry(widget).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(widget);
}
```

What is the proper way to save the edits to both objects in the Widget's Edit POST handler?  I tried just saving the Widget but I get an error about not being able to save a duplicate location.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you actually posted your actions as well, but based on the error you're getting I can hazard a guess.

When you post something to a controller action, the modelbinder attempts to bind what was posted to the parameters that action accepts. In your case, that's likely either an instance of `Widget` or both `Widget` and `Location`. Either way, the class(es) that have been instantiated *look* like entities because you've use your entity class(es), but they are not attached to your Entity Framework context. As a result, if you try to just save them, Entity Framework treats them like entirely new objects and attempts to save them as such. Since your location has an id, that id will conflict with the id of the existing object and you get your error. To correct this, you should do something like:

```
db.Locations.Attach(location);
```

Or

```
db.Entry(location).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Either way, you location will be attached to the context and then treated as an update instead of an insert.

For more information about entity states see: [Entity Framework Add/Attach and Entity States | MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Comment: Nice combination of explanation and code.  Could I get you to look at my other question too please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741422/list-of-objects-not-saved-when-db-updated

Comment: I guess I implemented what you said incorrectly.  I have posted my Actions in the OP. Please take a look...